# Not able to implement search using existing table in database in android

Tags: android

I am trying to implement search on user input. The serach results will be shown after searching the relevant option from database.

I have made this method to display the results

```
public Cursor getBooksBySearch(String query) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

String[] args={query};

return(getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id,chapter FROM chapters  WHERE chapter LIKE '%" + query + "%", args));
 }
```

Here the query is coming from an activity SearchResultAcitvity.java

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
  String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);


    ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.txt_query);
    dbBookHelper = new BooklistHelper(this);
    ourCursor = dbBookHelper.getBooksBySearch(query);
    startManagingCursor(ourCursor);
    adapter = new BookAdapter(ourCursor);
    myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    myListView.setOnItemClickListener(onListClick);
   }
```

I want to match this coming query string to get the results from my chapter table.
Can I just match the query string m getting in `String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY)` with the data in my database.
Using list view to display.

Please help me in this.
Let me know if you want more information

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

This will return list of data search by keyword

```
    public ArrayList<ObjectType> getSearchData(String keyword)
    {
    ArrayList<ObjectType> objectTypeList = new ArrayList<ObjectType>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

        String checkEntry="SELECT id,firstname,lastname FROM abc_table  WHERE firstname like  '%"+ keyword +"%'" +" or "+ "p.lastname like  '%"+ keyword +"%'";

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(checkEntry, null);
        try
        {
            //If entry exist then update 
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) 
            {
                do
                {
                    ObjectType objectType = new  ObjectType();
                    int PID=cursor.getInt(0);
                    String fname = cursor.getString(1);
                    String LastName = cursor.getString(2);


                    objectType.setFirstName(fname);
                    objectType.setLastName(LastName);

                    objectTypeList.add(objectType);

                }
                while(cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if(cursor != null)

                cursor.close();
        }

    return objectTypeList;
}
```

ObjectType is class

```
    public class ObjectType {

int id;
String firstName;
String lastName;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

}
Hope this ll help you.. :)

Comment: hi can u please tell what code i need to implement in my given code to get results . I have created a method to get results from there.

Comment: Also in above code of yours, what should be the <object type>??